# Can .ts audio files be combined using cat command in append mode to get the .mp3 file

Tags: audio, ffmpeg, audio-streaming, http-live-streaming, m3u8

I have some `.ts` files as part of an hls audio stream. Can I use the `cat` command to append them and get the .mp3 file. I'm curious what `ffmpeg` does to create the mp3 from `.ts` or `.m3u8` files so that I can implement it in a node server

Answer (score 5, accepted):

No. If you just concatenate them the result is still a MPEG-TS container file, i.e. basically a sequence of 188-byte TS packets. What you need is a MPEG-TS demuxer which would turn (decapsulate) the TS into a sequence of MP3 audio frames 
[1], more generally speaking the audio *elementary stream*.

[1] http://www.mp3-tech.org/programmer/frame_header.html